# How to get case_when in dplyr accept conditions from character

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when, rlang

I am trying to use `case_when` in shiny application in order to build an app, showing the preview of some selection policy expressed as a set of rules.

In the app, user can input expressions in `case_when` syntax, e.g.:

```
cond = "Age > 40 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0"
```

and they should be substituted in `case_when`.

I am looking at `rlang` and trying to figure out how to get an expression from a character vector, e.g.

```
tibble::tribble(~Age,23,26,32,50,51,52,25,49,34,54) %>% 
  mutate(result = case_when(!!!quos(syms(cond))))
```

but, apparently, fail to get it right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about with `parse_exprs`?

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
cond <- "Age > 40 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0"
cond <- gsub(",",";",cond)
repdata %>% mutate(result = case_when(!!!rlang::parse_exprs(cond)))
## A tibble: 10 x 2
#     Age result
#   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1    23      0
# 2    26      0
# 3    32      0
# 4    50      1
# 5    51      1
# 6    52      1
# 7    25      0
# 8    49      1
# 9    34      0
#10    54      1
```

This is required because `parse_expr` returns one expression, whereas `case_when` requires 2 or more expressions (separated by commas in code) to have 2 cases. Meanwhile, `parse_exprs` returns 2 or more expressions, but it splits expressions on `;`.

Data

```
repdata <- tibble::tribble(~Age,23,26,32,50,51,52,25,49,34,54)
```

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

repdata %>% 
  mutate(result = !!parse_expr(paste0("case_when(", cond, ")"))) %>% 
  head()
#    Age result
#  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1    23      0
#2    26      0
#3    32      0
#4    50      1
#5    51      1
#6    52      1
```

I will note that letting users execute arbitrary R code inside of a shiny app probably isn't the best idea, though. There is probably a better way to solve this using something like `cut`.